# These review audits are unfair, one of them was closed for the reason I flagged (and failed)

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

I have been suspended from reviewing because of these two failed review audits:

1. Apparently link-only answers are so bad that all of them should be completely removed from the site, but there are some link-only answers that are perfectly acceptable (albeit not high-quality).  Assuming that [this link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28430376) is not acceptable, while many others are, is unfair.
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28430669) did not have enough details to reproduce the problem<del>, and also it should belong on Super User because it is about the installation, not the code itself</del> as many users pointed out to me, this is on-topic, but still unclear.  **EDIT:** This question has recently been closed because of the *exact* flag I raised.

Both of these were very questionable and should be removed.  <del>I have succeeded on numerous review audits in this short period of time, and shouldn't be banned because my opinion was different then the computer's.</del>  As many users have pointed out to me, my banning was within the policy.  So this post is now about these two audits being unfair, but not about me being unbanned.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you find "your princess is in another castle, here is a link" acceptable as an answer?

Comment: As for point 2., the question is related to installing bootstrap, SASS, and vue.js/vue-cli. And since those are "*software tools commonly used by programmers*", I would say it's *not* off-topic just because "*it is about installation*". SuperUser is for general-purpose software. See related [Is this question about an npm install error *really* on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393439/2745495), [Are questions on programming tools installation/configuration on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308736/2745495).

Comment: also of note is that #2 is about Webpack configuration - folks on SuperUser would not be very fond of dealing with these types of questions (if you are not convinced, here is a small quote from their [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic): "and it is not about …programming and software development"

Comment: Though for point 2, it *does* lack details to reproduce the problem. I'm not an expert on vue.js and webpack and all that, but it could be better for the question to include steps used to install, versions of tools used on local env, etc. It has a score of 50 right now, so.. probably why audit picked it as a "good question".

Comment: I see no evidence of an unfair audit.

Comment: A review ban isn't that bad, is it? You're getting a break from clearing all the garbage on Stack.

Comment: That question clearly explains why those are bad answers though.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica That's different than a duplicate.  But even if that question were a duplicate, cross-site duplicates are still allowed.

Comment: matters of the second example of failed audit here were asked about and thoroughly answered in [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303795/839601)

Comment: @gnat Those questions are helpful but are not duplicates as they do not address these specific audits.  And the second question has just been closed by a moderator for the exact reason I flagged it and I have been banned because of it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both of the audits are just fine.

Take the first one:
[image]

This is, without a doubt in my mind, is Not An Answer (NAA). As it is link-only. A good way to identify if an answer is link-only is to mentally blackout the link and see if the answer is of any use without it.

[image]

> You can create your language model from scratch using this tutorial.

Sorry, which tutorial are you talking about? All I see is this text and a dead link (imagine it dead). Boom! flag as NAA and move on.

> Apparently link-only answers are so bad that all of them should be completely removed from the site

Yeah, absolutely, people come to SO to find answers, not links to answers elsewhere. That is our goal, we want to have all answers on-site. Also, links have a bad habit of dying now and then. When they die, all they leave behind are life-less answers that are utterly useless but that have been accepted and upvoted.

[image]

For the second one, all installations that relate to software development are on-topic (IIRC). This even includes the installation of text-editors/IDEs.

> [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28430669) did not have enough details

Although to be fair, I do see your point with this one. It doesn't provide steps to reproduce the problem, which it should. As [Gino Mempin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405645/these-review-audits-are-unfair/405648#comment828192_405645)
noted, the 50+ upvotes on it must have caused the system to pick it up. Because it was asked 22 days ago, I have left a comment asking the author to add some steps if possible. This question IMO is somewhat of a failure from the reviewers' side. It shouldn't have been allowed to receive answers (when it was posted) unless the author added the steps needed. But as fate would have it, it ended up getting a lot of upvotes and answers and is now useful. So, for situations like this, I highly recommend opening the link to the post and inspecting it *in-person*. Not only will you be able to catch audits but you will also be able to avoid situations like this. Audits aren't some exam that you have to pass from time to time. They are just the systems way of checking if you are paying attention or not (<s>and an opportunity for the community bot to cosplay as other users</s>). The fact that you are opening and inspecting each link isn't "*cheating*", it is what is expected from a reviewer...

Don't worry about review bans too much. From my experience, they are a good opportunity to learn how the site works and what is and isn't on-topic here.

---

Turns out the first answer was spam! I totally missed that "mlcom" could be "Machine Learning Community" (their username). Thanks to [Laurel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405645/these-review-audits-are-unfair/405648?noredirect=1#comment828335_405648) for pointing it out. So, I googled "github mlcom" and found https://github.com/mlcom and lo and behold their username is *Machine Learning Community*! So it is in fact spam.

It is undisclosed affiliation. Such posts can be hard to detect but once you do I would recommend **mod flagging** it instead of **spam flagging**. I have had spam flags on such posts rejected because it isn't easy to find the corelation. Instead, explain yourself in a mod flag. Something like:

> This user is affiliated to this website. See https://github.com/mlcom, their username there is "Machine Learning Community" which matches that on SO. Please inform them how to disclose affiliation properly and delete this NAA.

Comment: If you haven't been review banned, then you haven't reviewed.

Comment: @10Rep guess this means I've got 95 Steward badges without reviewing

Comment: I’m not sure that NAA was the right flag for the first answer. It looks like **spam** to me (considering the name of the OP and the sub domain of the link).

Comment: So I should examine every link on every post that I review?

Comment: @Anonymous yes.

Comment: *all installations that relate to software development are on-topic* - That's a subject of some debate. ... [here's one discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330413/10871073) but I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 4):

From a cursory look at your profile, it seems that you are relatively new to reviewing on Stack Overflow. So, the first thing I would say is that you shouldn't interpret this Review Suspension as a *punishment* but, rather, as a *learning experience* (very much echoing the similar point made by Yatin). I've done a lot of reviewing (though not as much as gnat) and – although you (and many others) may find it hard to believe – I have enjoyed a number of these "Review Vacations!" Also, if this is your first suspension, it is presumably for only a few days (the length increases each time, if you receive multiple suspensions within a given timeframe).

Take the opportunity to learn more about reviewing; there are a number of posts on Meta.SE, and here on Meta.SO, explaining what is expected of reviewers, and this is a good starting point: [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/616624) Please be assured that, although you may currently feel disheartened that the system has 'given you a kick', site curation by users such as yourself is important, valuable and (when done properly) greatly appreciated by the Community as a whole.

---

On the specific audits you failed, I would *mostly* support the points made by Yatin: the first is clearly a "link only" answer (and also spam), as the answer is completely devoid of use without following the link.

The second is more dubious. This has now <strike>received close votes</strike> been closed (most likely as a consequence of your raising it here), and will thus (hopefully) not be used again as an audit. Over time, we all occasionally encounter bad audits; it's never nice but, individually, such 'system errors' won't trigger a suspension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm fine with a short review ban, but I'm worried that next time I'll be banned for a much longer time now that I've been banned once.  Am I going to get a 1 month ban next time I fail an audit?  It doesn't seem to care that I've succeeded on about 80% of audits.

Comment: (1) Passing audits counts for nothing (no reward other than your own satisfaction). (2) The suspension length increase is, IIRC, roughly a doubling each time. I *think* the count 'resets' after 30 days without a failed audit. So, when you're 'back in', take things slowly and carefully.

Comment: @Anonymous If you're wrong on 20%, that needs improving.

Comment: @khelwood I'm new to reviewing.  These two are the only two I ever failed.  I just haven't received many audits.

Comment: That's cool. I'm sure you'll improve.But "I've succeeded on about 80% of audits" isn't an point against the suspension.

Comment: @khelwood It is if the only ones that you ever failed were unfair.

Comment: @Anonymous Like I said, passed audits count for *nothing*. Nada! Zilch! Only if you *fail* an audit does the system 'notice' you.

Comment: @AdrianMole I understand that.  I'm no longer saying that I should be unbanned.  I'm just pointing out that this system is somewhat flawed, but I understand that it's necessary for the problematic reviewers.

Comment: Think of audits in the same way as passport inspections. If you attempt to cross an international border with a fake/expired/invalid passport, you'll get grief. But, there's no 'medal' for having a good passport - just the reward of *not* being huckled away.

Comment: In heart surgery, saying "I only tore 2 arteries! I managed to fix the other 25!" is not acceptable. Even though 92 percent of the arteries are fixed, the patient is dead and the damage has been done. You won't get a reward for the other 25 arteries.