# Why was this audit answer low quality?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, specific-audit

The question was "What is the difference between data mining and text mining?" and the answer I was [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28886904) looked like this:

> Data Mining refers to scraping or mining data from large amounts of
> information. The term is really a contradiction. Thus, data mining
> should have been more suitably named as knowledge mining which
> emphasis on mining from huge amounts of data. It is a computational
> process of discovering patterns in large data sets including methods
> at intersection of Artificial Intelligence, Machine Learning,
> statistics, and database systems. Alternative Names of Data Mining
> Here are some alternative names of data mining that you should know:
>
> 1. Business Intelligence
> 2. Data Archeology
> 3. Data Dredging
> 4. Data/Pattern Analysis
> 5. Information Harvesting
> 6. Knowledge Discovery (Mining) in Databases (KDD)
> 7. Knowledge Extraction
>
> Key Properties of Data Mining Let’s go though some key properties of
> Data Mining:
>
> 1. Automatic discovery of patterns
> 2. Prediction of likely outcomes
> 3. Creation of actionable information
> 4. Focus on large datasets and databases
>
> Data Mining Process Data Mining is a process of determining different
> summaries, models, and derived prices from a given collection of
> information. The general experimental procedure modified to
> data-mining problem involves the following steps:
>
> 1. State Problem and Formulate Hypothesis: - In the given step, a modeler generally requires a group of variables for indefinite
>    dependency and, if possible, a common sort of this dependency as an
>    initial hypothesis. In effective data-mining applications, this
>    support does not stop within primary phase. It endures during whole
>    data-mining procedure.
> 2. Collect Data: - This step cares about how data is produced and picked up. Usually, there are two separate potentials. The main is
>    when data-generation procedure is under control of an expert
>    (modeler).Also, it is important to use data later for applying and
>    testing a model come from an unknown, equivalent, sampling
>    distribution. If this is often not the case, expected model cannot be
>    effectively used in a final application of results.
>
> Data Processing In the observational setting, information is
> frequently “gathered” from data warehouses, data marts, and prevailing
> databases. Data preprocessing generally includes at least two general
> tasks:
>
> 1. Outlier Detection: - Outliers are unusual data values that are not according to most observations. Normally, outliers’ result comes from
>    coding, recording errors, measuring errors, and, sometimes, are
>    natural, abnormal values. Such non-representative samples can really
>    affect model process later.
> 2. Encoding, Scaling, and Selecting Features: - Data preprocessing contains some steps like differing types of encoding and variable
>    scaling. For example, one feature with range [0, 1] and other with
>    range [100, 1000] will not have a comparable weight within useful
>    method. They are going to inspire vital data-mining results inversely.
>
> Data Mining Challenges Enlisted below are the various challenges
> involved in Data Mining.
>
> 1. Data Mining requires data collection and large databases that is impossible to manage.
> 2. The data mining procedure needs domain specialists that are again difficult to find.
> 3. Integration from varied databases is a complex process.
> 4. The organizational level practices need to be modified to use the data mining results. Restructuring the process requires effort and cost.

I don't know much about data mining myself but the only thing I didn't particularly like about this answer was it didn't mention text mining. That being said, I learned something about data mining by reading it. Certainly not "readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful" as the "STOP! Look and listen" banner suggested after failing the audit.

Comment: Can you link to the actual audit? Did the answer contain links?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28886904

Comment: Looks suspiciously spammy to me.... was there any link? If so, then this answer was clearly spam.

Comment: I looked up [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794236/what-is-the-difference-between-data-mining-and-text-mining) because it didn't sound like a concrete programming problem. It was closed, downvoted and deleted. The answer itself was flagged and deleted as spam.

Comment: The answer was given by a user whose name sounds suspiciously like a product. The profile is also very...marketing-y.

Comment: @VLAZ I see that now. Besides the sly advertisement I didn't think it was too bad of an answer

Comment: The first line contains a link to something called `Web Data Mining Service` by something called `Scraping Intelligence` which is the same as the username. As a reviewer, this should raise a red flag

Comment: [Screenshot for people with less than 10k rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKztT.png). The answer from the audit is the last one in that image.

Comment: @BradyDean 1. the question itself is off-topic. 2. The answer was VERY thorough by a user with 1 rep who also had a link to a web scraping tool in the answer (without even explaining why it's there (very sneaky). The account name sounds like a product. Checking the account information, reveals more marketing talk and more links to some product. "*I didn't think it was too bad of an answer*" should read "it seems A LOT LIKE SPAM and I tried to flag it myself but hit the wrong button".

Comment: @VLAZ For all I knew the question was on-topic. All I had to go off of was the title since the question was deleted

Comment: "*For all I knew the question was on-topic.*" should read "Thanks for the tip, I'd review the help information to more accurately asses what is and isn't on-topic". Because to me the question seemed off-topic before even looking it up - just by the title you posted here. I then went and looked that title via a search engine and got a cached link to the deleted question which did confirm that yes - the question *was* correctly marked as off-topic. It doesn't sound like a practical programming problem and it indeed wasn't. For years. Managed to attract spam and was closed and deleted then.

Comment: @BradyDean if you didn't have much to go on, you should have skipped it.

Comment: @BradyDean You *ignored* a bunch of signs that the answer was bad but now I'm somehow at fault for pointing out that your reviewing needs work? You also ignored a dead giveaway in the question title. Nothing magical about it - it's not a title of a Stack Overflow problem. That's it. If you really want to blame me, please do that *instead* of reviewing as you don't seem to want to improve on that front. With trying to blame me and all.

Comment: @10Rep When I read VLAZ's comments it feels like my effort has gone out the window. I don't look at the review queues often and in this case I wanted to see how I messed up. Insinuating I hit the wrong button when I hit the button I felt was right.

Comment: Seeing something really bad and not acting on it is worse than not seeing something really bad.

Comment: Nothing jumped out as a red flag to me, that's why I OK'd the answer. I can't *ignore* a red flag if it never occurred to me in the first place. I'm new at this reviewing stuff.

Comment: After reviewing a lot, it slowly becomes easier and easier to identify spam. For some people it's become second nature. That just becomes better over time.

Comment: [I've been in the exact same situation as you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405645/8384089), and a lot of the audits are tricky or outright unfair.  But if you get banned, keep reviewing and the ban only lasts so long.  Try to think about why the correct action is what the audit says it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019287) is spam, and there are various indicators of this.

To start off, the answer is a wall of text and contains a single link inside it. This alone is suspicious, which should prompt you to take a look at the [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15458309), which shows that the user is affiliated with the linked website. Since they haven't disclosed affiliation, this is already spam. The username "Scraping Intelligence" is also a bit suspicious, but I personally tend not to read too much into that.

Something you should do when faced with a spam link contained in a wall of text, is to see if the text is plagiarized. You can do this by searching online for a few sentences at a time, and if it's plagiarized, you'll get a hit soon enough. In this case the text appears to be copied almost verbatim from a [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-mining-process) article.

At this point, your only option is to raise a flag. While a Spam flag might be sufficient in this case, it may not *obviously* be spam, and so you could raise a custom "In need of moderator intervention" flag, and explain the evidence you've found. Of course, this was an audit, but the action of raising a flag would have let you pass the audit.

I understand that this might seem like a lot of work to put in, and that's reasonable, in which case you can always Skip, there's no shame in that. But if you see a post with the indicators mentioned above, you shouldn't say it looks OK unless you've verified that it's not spam.

Comment: And if it didn't have those other spam tell-tales, the tone makes it "smell" like a copy & paste job, which is, as you mention, easy to verify. And so if it didn't merit a spam flag it would certainly warrant a custom flag as plagiarism.