# Reversing the review ban if the flag that caused it was accepted

Tags: feature-request, review-suspension

[It's happened before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405645/8384089): I flagged [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28430669) as needs details or clarity and got banned because of it.  The question was then closed as needs details or clarity.  If a flag is accepted, and that's against the audit, obviously the audit is wrong.  The ban should be reversed afterwards.

Comment: I don't quite understand why people keep using a system that constantly works against them.

Comment: @KevinB Because otherwise nothing would get reviewed...

Comment: I don't disagree... however... it's just such an awful experience.

Comment: @KevinB I always look at the post page for zero-scored posts, makes the experience a whole lot less awful...

Comment: I mean the whole... constantly feeling like the system is trying to fool you with audits, just waiting to ban you for taking an appropriate action just because it's different from the herd.

Comment: @Anonymous Voting on any of the Meta sites is different than on the main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although they can also reflect that. As a consequence, downvotes on Meta should not be automatically considered to mean that there are problems with the post. On the other hand, it doesn't hurt to double-check that the post quality is good.

Comment: Why is a question that is viewed so often in such a short time period, with so many upvotes, closed as unclear? Sure it would be nice if the steps to reproduce are in the question, but if so many people are able to identify their problem with that post, it serves its purpose to do if you ask me.

Comment: @Ivar No, it is unclear.  It gives the error message, but doesn't give any more details.  The only reason people could answer it is because they had the same problem too.  And the point is, if a mod did what you said to do, that means you took the right action.

Comment: @Anonymous That's the whole goal of Stack Overflow. For people to find answers to programming problems they are facing, that others have faced before.

Comment: @Ivar If an answerer has to just happen to have the same problem, the question's unclear.  Feel free to cast a reopen vote; arguing about the mods' decision isn't the point of this post.  The point is, if your flag is accepted, it's consistent with what the mods think, so it should be the right action.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not sure who you are referring to with "mods", [but the question was not closed by a diamond moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66082397/timeline#history_45530fea-1c78-4d8c-adae-d585d1c2a422). It was closed by three community members with the close vote privilege, which marked your flag as helpful.

Comment: @Ivar My point still stands.

Comment: While this would be reasonable as "feature-request" the example of a "bad audit" is super questionable. I'm pretty sure everyone who uses vue.js+sass finds that the question indeed has MRE... while everyone else can't see one there. Could that question be improved - definitly, but calling it clear-cut off-topic is a stretch.

Comment: This post has been viewed 74k times in 3 months! That's more than 800 times a day! It is highly upvoted with highly upvoted Answers. Which I'd guess would **not** have gotten that many votes if it hadn't been useful. There's barely been a day where this post didn't get an upvote. I find the post to be clear. Just install as they say in the post, and you'll get the same error.

Comment: A single audit failure doesn't cause a review ban. It requires multiple failures

Comment: @charlietfl Multiple failures are easy when you're banned for having a different opinion.

Comment: Just FYI: The actions you take on review audits are not recorded by the system as actual actions on the post. The flag which you went through the motions of raising in the review, and which caused you to fail the audit, wasn't *actually* raised. Thus, unless you separately raised a flag on the question by going to the question page and actually raising one (doing so again from your point of view), then there will be no flag raised by you on the post. While that doesn't mean that what you want couldn't happen, it does mean that it's more complicated than seeing you get a helpful flag.

Comment: @Anonymous - "I always look at the post page for zero-scored posts" - If you do this then how are you failing to identify questions that are obviously audits?  This is the at least the second time you have complain about failing audits in the last 6 months when you have made the obvious incorrect decision during a review audit

Comment: @SecurityHound This isn't be complaining about failed audits, it's the same audit I used in the other question and that isn't the point of the question...

Answer (score 5):

I don't find the need for such a feature.

Let's say you review an audit and you fail because you flagged it, but the question is not closed. (This is the situation you are in right now). If the question gets closed *after* your review, then one thing has to be clarified:

*Is the closure of the question correct or incorrect?*

I claim no experience over vue.js, but it looks to me as though the question does not deserve to be closed. Other than a large number of upvotes, it has a lot of seemingly high quality answers <sup>1</sup>, and has a lot of views.

So in this case, I argue that the closure of the question was incorrect, as the question was useful, and we don't close useful questions.

But let's assume the opposite for a second: the question was closed correctly. In this case, you may post to meta explaining that the question was closed after your audit review, and that you should be unbanned because you made the right decision.

> If a flag is accepted, and that's against the audit, obviously the audit is wrong. The ban should be reversed afterwards.

Using an automated system to overrule the decision of .... yet another automated system doesn't seem like an enticing idea to me. Only humans should be able to review unban any user before their suspension ends. It's just... more safe, because flags can be handled wrongly.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I claim no expertise over vue.js, but those answers look somewhat high quality to me.</sub>

Comment: Flags can be handled wrongly?  So can manual unbans.

Comment: @Anonymous yes, sure, but mods are the only people who can manually unban you, and they will only do that if meta consensus is reached. It's much more likely that the meta crowd will not make a wrong decision.

Comment: Audits are supposed to be blatant, and if the flag is accepted that means it isn't blatant because mods represent the ideal reviewers.

Comment: I don't think there needs to be a meta consensus for an unban. Just a moderator evaluation the suspension and the reason for it :) I'm pretty sure one can raise a flag and explain as well :)

Comment: @Scratte not all the time... but in this case it seems like the best thing to do because the community is unilaterally the best source to decide whether a closure is incorrect or not (at least relatively :)).

Comment: "we don't close useful questions" - untrue since for example duplicate closures are also closures and duplicates can be useful in their own right. We don't *delete* useful content.

Comment: @Anonymous - Who with any authority has indicated that a moderator accepting a flag represents the "ideal reviewer"?  If I receive a gray hair for the numbers of actions, that could cause a flag to automatically be accepted without any interaction by a moderator, I would have a head full of gray hairs.